# How to connect cvat postgres db to Dbeaver

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile, dbeaver

Docker container for cvat_db has following settings:

```
services: 
  cvat_db:
    container_name: cvat_db
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_DB: cvat
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    volumes:
      cvat_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

networks:
 cvat
```

While below is the connection setting in dbeaver, where "HOST IP" i have put the IP address where cvat is hosted.

[Dbeaver Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWRii.png)

I'm getting error of timeout connection. So, I want to know how to connect postgres database to dbeaver.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the following in mind:

- Postgres always need a password according to their docs.
- Do not create custom networks if it is not really needed. Use the default bridge network instead.
- Do you connect with Postgres from another docker container or from your host system? If you connect from your host system add `ports` with `5432:5432`.
- mount your volumes to a subpath instead of named volumes

Example compose file:

```
version: '3.9'
services: 
  cvat_db:
    container_name: cvat_db
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: cvat
    volumes:
      - ./cvat_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

I wrote an [article](https://medium.com/@datails/full-stack-development-with-docker-compose-c517ec826696) about docker compose networking, perhaps it helps.